# (C99)Expand a macro in a different macro

Tags: c, macros, gcc4.6

I have a function in my program that takes 3 arguments. Some times in the code there is a macro defining 2 of these parameters.

So this:

```
void func(int x, int y, int z){...}
```

Can be invoked like this:

```
#define PAR 10,20
int z = 3;
func(PAR, z);
```

Now, I need to change my code so that the function is called like a macro for another function.

```
#define func(X,Y,Z) func2(X,Y,Z,#Z)
```

This works fine if X and Y are really passed as variables. Is there any way to make it work also with the macro PAR?

I'm using GCC 4.6

Comment: Maybe it is, maybe it isn't. What I know is that you shouldn't do it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with an extra level of indirection, (ab)using variadic
macros:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PAR 2,3
#define F(...) G(__VA_ARGS__)
#define G(a,b,c) H(a,b,c)
void H(int a, int b, int c) {
  printf("%d %d %d\n", a , b, c);
}
int main() {
  F(PAR, 42);
  return 0;
}
```

There is probably a better solution for the underlying problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, I don't believe so.  When you define

```
#define func(X,Y,Z) func2(X,Y,Z,#Z)
```

You're defining a [function-like macro](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Function-like-Macros.html).  **func(X,Y,Z)** actually takes three arguments - [and it has to take three arguments](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Macro-Arguments.html#Macro-Arguments).  Remember, the **preprocessor** and **not the compiler** is interpreting **func(PAR, Z)**.

I've struggled to find any documentation, but it makes sense that the first thing the preprocessor will do (considering that **func()** is the outer element) is to check to see if the arguments to **func()** are valid.  Then it will place the arguments into **func2()** and will then expand any macros that were passed as arguments.  The code I placed below seems to back up this claim.

Following this logic, the preprocessor will see that **func(PAR, Z)** isn't a valid call because an argument is missing, which will then throw the error

```
13:12: error: macro "func" requires 3 arguments, but only 2 given
```

**func(X, Y, Z)** will work so long as **X** and **Y** are valid macros or variables.

Code (*this will give you warnings because there is no function declaration*, but the output will be "**3 14 3**" as expected):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define PAR 10,20
#define MAR 3
#define WAR 14
#define func(X,Y,Z) print(X, Y, Z)

int Z = 3;

int main(void){

        func(MAR,WAR,Z);

        return 0;
}

void print(int x, int y, int c){

        printf("%d %d %d\n", x, y, c);

}
```

Out of curiosity, why are you doing this (I don't have enough reputation to comment yet FYI).

Comment: If you add a layer of indirection and have the invocation of `func` happen within another macro body, consider that the number of arguments can't be counted until it's time to expand `func` - which won't be identified by the expander until it's done substituting variables into the wrapper macro's body, at which point it's possible for `PAR` to have already been expanded (certainly if it was passed in as an argument to the wrapper), changing the number of arguments there to count.